# Code retrieving two string from Firebase and setting the second one as the value of String 'hDescription'

Tags: android, firebase, android-adapter, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an Android app and I'm fetching some data from Firebase. The data has two strings and both of them are getting fetched.

I am storing the data fetched in a `String` variable named `hDescription`. Then I am showing these two string in a list using [FastAdapter](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter).

Full code of adapter:

```
public class HRequest extends AbstractItem<HRequest, HRequest.ViewHolder> {

    public String homelessDescription;

    public HRequest() {

    }

    public HRequest(String hDescription) {
        this.hDescription = hDescription;
    }

    // Fast Adapter methods
    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return R.id.recycler_view;
    }
    @Override
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.h_request_list_row;
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(ViewHolder holder) {
        super.bindView(holder);

        holder.hDescription.setText(hDescription);

    }
    // Manually create the ViewHolder class
    protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView hDescription;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            hDescription = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.hDescriptionH);

        }
    }

}
```

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Now what I have done next is I have setup `FastAdapter.OnClickListener<HRequest>()` like this:

```
FastItemAdapter<HRequest> fastItemAdapter.withOnClickListener(new FastAdapter.OnClickListener<HRequest>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClick(View v, IAdapter<HRequest> adapter, HRequest item, int position) {
                Intent hRequestExtendedIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HRequestExtended.class);
                hRequestExtendedIntent.putExtra("hDescription", hDescription);
                startActivity(hRequestExtendedIntent);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I'm sending the `hDesciption` to another activity using `Intent` and using that string to assign the value to a string in that another activity.

The problem is that upon clicking on item having "help me out" as a string, the string I am getting in the another activity is not "help me out", but "666777".

What I want is I want to show the respective string on which the user has clicked. For ex- if the user clicked on "help me out" one then in the next activity the string "help me out" should be shown.

Comment: can you show the full code of your adapter ??

Comment: @jankigadhiya please see the edited question.